# What is going on with this declension situation? "Ich bekomme gute Noten" but

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

When I google translate the sentence `I get good grades` I get `Ich bekomme gute Noten`, which is fine since the `e` ending denotes an accusative plural case, as far as I can tell.

However, if I try `I don't get good grades`, the translation becomes `Ich bekomme keine guten Noten`. Why does the appearance of a `keine` leads to the adjective declining with `n`? Which grammatical rule explains this?

Comment: Good catch. You have to compare "Ich bekomme gute Noten" (obeys strong declension) with "...keine guten Noten" (mixed declension), explained in the accepted answer to the linked question.